# Nautilus does not start automatically on boot

Tags: nautilus

I recently upgraded the gnome shell to 3.14 and since then every time I boot my desktop the nautilus does not start. There is no response when I click the Files icon or type
`nautilus` in the terminal. However when I restart the nautilus by typing `nautilus -q`
the file manager starts working again. I have to restart the nautilus every time I boot my computer. Need a solution.

Comment: This needs more attention